# docker exec java app background attach logs

Tags: java, spring, logging, docker

For a Java app running inside a docker container where should I output my logs to so that docker logs -f can read the log output of the java application after its been running for a while?

I execute the java app that is inside the active docker container with something like the following

```
docker exec -d container-name java -jar /path-to-jar/java-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

So far so good it runs my Spring Boot java app.

**Would either of the following approaches work?**

```
docker exec -d container-name java -jar /path-to-jar/java-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar > /var/log/docker-id.log
```

Or setting the java log path settings to a particular destination?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}/}spring.log}"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml" />
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Your first solution wont work because if your run it with `-d` it will only output the name of the container (it should work if you run it with `-it`). The second one should work if the file is written in a mounted volume.

Comment: I do not want to attach it to the terminal because when I close the terminal it will exit the process.  So what I am looking to do is be able to access the logs via docker logs -f %container name% with a process that is running in the background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run an application in docker and be able to view the logs then running it like the following will work.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM base-image
COPY app.jar /opt/app.jar
CMD ["java","-jar","/opt/rate-upload-tool.jar"]
```

**Build Docker Image**

```
docker build -t java-app-image-name .
```

**Run docker image in background**

```
docker run --name app-container-name -d java-app-image-name
```

Following this you will be able to view logs of docker

```
docker logs -f app-container-name
```